# How to insert temporary (without insert to table) in this query?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

```
select * 
from
(
    select temp.agamaid, temp.jum_peg, nvl(temp.jeniskelamin,'L') jeniskelamin,
           case when temp.jeniskelamin = 'L' then 1
                when temp.jeniskelamin = 'P' then 2
                else 0
           end as num
    from
    (
        select agama.agamaid, AGAMA.agama, PEGAWAI.jeniskelamin,
               count(PEGAWAI.pegawaiid) jum_peg
        from agama
            left join pegawai on PEGAWAI.agamaid = AGAMA.agamaid
        group by AGAMA.agamaid, AGAMA.agama, PEGAWAI.jeniskelamin
    ) temp 
) temp
    left join master_jeniskelamin mjk on temp.jeniskelamin = mjk.id_jk
order by temp.agamaid, temp.jeniskelamin
```

That query just give me a result like this:

[image: Not my expectation output]

But I want result, that agamaid in (3,4,5) also has another jeniskelamin which it hasn't have yet.

Could you help me please? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    a.agamaid,
    COUNT(p.pegawaiid) AS jum_peg,
    p.jeniskelamin,
    CASE
        WHEN p.jeniskelamin = 'L' THEN 1
        WHEN p.jeniskelamin = 'P' THEN 2
        ELSE 0
    END AS num,
    mjk.id_jk
FROM
    master_jeniskelamin mjk
    CROSS JOIN agama a
    LEFT JOIN pegawai p
        ON p.jeniskelamin = mjk.id_jk
        AND p.agamaid = a.agamaid
GROUP BY
    a.agamaid,
    mjk.id_jk,
    p.jeniskelamin
ORDER BY
    a.agamaid,
    mjk.id_jk
```